# Calling a VB property from its own accessor

Tags: vb.net, properties

I am trying to find documentation on the behavior of a VB property when you access the property name from within its accessor. I expected in the first line of the Get the `MyMinions` property access to be recursive(ish), but its not. The Value of `MyMinions` inside its accessor is always `Nothing`, why is it always nothing and is this documented anywhere?

```
Public Class MyJob

    Public Sub New()
        MinionCount = 3
    End Sub

    Public Property MinionCount As Int32

    Public Property MyMinions As List(Of Object)
        Get
            If MinionCount > 0 AndAlso MyMinions Is Nothing Then
                _myMinions = New List(Of Object)() 'here would be DAL call
            End If
            Return _myMinions
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Object))
            _myMinions = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _myMinions As List(Of Object) = Nothing

End Class
```

Comment: The IDE should be warning you that `MyMinions` is used before it has been assigned a value

Comment: Just to clarify, this was a bug I found, I am not trying to make this code work, I want to understand the behavior better

Comment: The getter acts like a function, in VB you *can* assign the return to the function name.  As such it acts like a typed placeholder variable, thus `MyMinions` is always nothing at the start of the (quasi) function until you assign something to it.

Comment: Exacly like plutonix said. In that case, MyMinions is like a hidden variable. Try "Me.MyMinions" instead.

Comment: @Plutonix That clarifies to me how its working and makes sense. Does microsoft document this behavior anywhere, it seems peculiar enough that it should be pointed out. I cannot find anything on MSDN that describing this behavior of the VB property.

Comment: It is legacy behavior going back to very early versions of BASIC that has been maintained.

Comment: @the_lotus Nice lotus, `System.StackOverflowException` , makes sense to me, its recursing if you use `Me.MyMinions`

Comment: `3. In the case of a Function, an implicit local variable is also initialized called the function return variable whose name is the function’s name, whose type is the return type of the function and whose initial value is the default of its type.`  10.1.1.3 of the VB Language Spec

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks, never thought to look in the language spec.,  section 9.7.1 helped me also. If you want, post your comments and ill accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Property getter acts much like a Function where the name is an implicit, typed local variable.  From 9.7.1 of the VB Spec:

> A special local variable, which is implicitly declared in the Get
>   accessor body's declaration space with the same name as the property,
>   represents the return value of the property...

The spec includes the following example:

```
ReadOnly Property F(i As Integer) As Integer
    Get
        If i = 0 Then
            F = 1    ' Sets the return value.
        Else
            F = F(i - 1) ' Recursive call.
        End If
    End Get
End Property
```

Rather than `Return 1` the code uses `F = 1` to assign a value to the local variable / function name for the return.

Thus, in your code, `MyMinions` is the local return variable and will be `Nothing` (the default for a List) until you assign something to it.  Since it is a *local* variable, it doesn't result in recursion.

---

The prop getter works enough like a function that the explanation there (10.1.1) may also be helpful:

> 3. In the case of a Function, an implicit local variable is also
>      initialized called the function return variable whose name is the
>      function’s name, whose type is the return type of the function and
>      whose initial value is the default of its type.

The behaviors could diverge at some point.